# Get current ApplicationPath value in Jersey resource method

Tags: jersey

I have a jersey 2.0 application using mcv with freemarker templates. In one template I have a form whose action is to resubmit to same url. Say the form url is:

```
http://my-domain.com/app-base-path/my-form
```

So the application annotaion is : `@ApplicationPath("app-base-path")`
and resource path annotation is `@Path("my-form")`. Great.

I'm trying to set the form action dynamically to be:

```
<form name="settings" action="${model.formAction}" method="post">
```

where action should equal: app-base-path/my-form
I'm trying to set the value in the resource by injecting UriInfo. This is what I'm getting:

```
formAction = uriInfo.getPath();
//result formAction = "my-form"
```

How can I retrieve the path including app-base-path?
No javascript please!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute URI with `uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()`, which will return a `URI` with the *full* URI of the corresponding resource method.

```
http://localhost:8080/app-base-path/myform
```

A URI can be broken down in distinct parts, which the `URI` class has specific methods to obtain those parts

```
scheme            authority              path
--------------------------------------------------------
http    ://     localhost:8080     /app-base-path/myform
```

The URI class has method to obtain all of those.

```
uri.getScheme()
uri.getAuthority()
uri.getPath()
```

I'm pretty sure I don't need to tell you which one you want :-)

Comment: As an aside, to answer the title question, if you only want to the app path, you can use `UriInfo.getBaseUri().getPath()`

Comment: I may have over simplified it. My local dev tomcat hosts a few web apps each with a base context path. Like : localhost/app-name/app-base-path/my-form. I only need the part relative to app-name.

Comment: `UriBuilder.fromPath(uriInfo.getBaseUri().getPath()).path(FormResource.class).build().toString()`.. should work

Comment: Or `uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(FormResource.class).build()`